# Как организовать вход данных?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    freopen("y.in", "r", stdin);
    freopen("y.out", "w", stdout);

    int a, s = 0;

    while(scanf("%d", &a))
    {
                      s += a;
    }

    cout << s << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

Входной файл содержит n целых чисел. Надо вывести одно целое число - сумму всех во входном файле. Я попробовал сделать как показано выше и не получается. Подскажите что сделать чтоб заработало.

---

А можно ли это осуществить с помощью конструкции cin? а не scanf()

Comment: Прошу предлагать методы, которые смогут заработать в консоли, в случае если я закомментирую //freopen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Напишите условие правильно

```
while(scanf("%d", &a) == 1)
```

И все будет работать.

И маленькое замечание - не смешивайте "сишный" - scanf ввод и "c++" вывод std::cout.

Почему не работает Ваше условие? `scanf` возвращает кол-во прочитанных чисел. И в Вашем случае оно будет возвращать 1. Но когда данные закончатся, то возвратит `-1`. А тот `while`, что записан у Вас равнозначный такому:

```
while(scanf("%d", &a) != 0)
```

Comment: ок, учту, спасибо

Comment: а freopen() это сишная или с++ функция?

Comment: вообще то сишная. Но нельзя так говорить, если честно. Ее можно (а иногда и нужно) использовать в с++. Главное в том, что бы не смешивать стили.

Comment: >> А тот while, что записан у Вас равнозначный такому:
>> while(scanf("%d", &a) != 1)

Наверное таки **!= 0** ?

Comment: наверное:)

Answer (score 5):

@risonyo, после `freopen(...,stdin/stdout)` `cin`/`cout` будут работать с файлом.

Думал, Вы уже давно со всем этим разобрались, но если интересно, смотрите:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

/*
 * Переоткрывает с заданными файлами stdin, stdout
 * или печатает help
 *
 * Returns 0 if OK
 */
static int do_inout (int ac, char *av[])
{
  if (av[1]) {
    if (strcmp(av[1], "-h") == 0 || strcmp(av[1], "--help") == 0) {
      cerr << "Usage: " << av[0] <<
        " [input-file|- [output-file]]\n" <<
        " `-' means stdin\n";
      return -1;
    }
    if (strcmp(av[1],"-"))
      if (!freopen(av[1], "r", stdin)) {
        cerr << "Can't freopen stdin to " << av[1] << 
          " : " << strerror(errno) << '\n';
        return 1;
      }
    if (av[2])
      if (!freopen(av[2], "w", stdout)) {
        cerr << "Can't freopen stdout to " << av[1] << 
          " : " << strerror(errno) << '\n';
        return 2;
      }
  }
  return 0;
}

int main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int err = do_inout(ac, av); // Returns -1 если help просили

  if (!err) {
    int sum = 0, a;

    while (1) {
      cin >> a;
      if (cin.good())
        sum += a;
      else
        break;
    }
    if (cin.eof())
      cout << "Sum: " << sum << '\n';
    else {
      err++;
      cerr << "Read error\n";
    }
  }

  return err > 0 ? 1 : 0; // при ошибке возвратим 1, если OK или help, то вернем 0
}
```

При запуске без аргументов читает и пишет на консоль. Первый аргумент имя входного файла, второй выходного. Если первый аргумент `-`, то читает консоль, а если `-h` или `--help` — печатает:

```
Usage: ./a.out [input-file|- [output-file]]
 `-' means stdin
```

При попытке ввода не целого числа, пишет сообщение об ошибке и завершается с кодом 1.

Что непонятно — спрашивайте.

Answer (score 1):

Способ через потоки C++

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
ifstream in("input.txt");   //создаём поток ввода из файла
ofstream out("output.txt"); //создаём поток вывода в файл

int a=0,s=0;

while(true)
{
in>>a;//читаем из потока(файла input.txt) одно значение
if (in.eof()) break;
s+=a;
}

cout<<s;   //вывод сумму на консоль
//out<<s;  вывод суммы в поток(файл output.txt)

in.close();
out.close();
return 0;
}
```

cin читает данные с консоли. Я не знаю, может быть с помощью него и можно считать данные из файла, но это уже будет каким-то извращением, на мой взгляд.

Comment: а через cin можно?

Comment: добавил в конец ответа по счёт cin.

Comment: а даже елси не из файла просто консоль? метод выше будет работать и для консоли, твой нет

Comment: freopen поддерживает как раз свободно cin и cout, просто как в консоли работаешь и все, только тут файлы

Comment: Если хочешь, могу написать решения с чтением данных из консоли.
С чего ты взял, что тот код будет работать и для консоли? Есть файл-будет работать, нет файла-будет ошибка.

Comment: while(!in.eof()) //метод eof() возвращает 1 если дошли до конца файла
    {
     in>>a;//читаем из потока(файла input.txt) одно значение
     s+=a;
    }

Грубейшая ошибка определения достижения конца файла. Флаг `eofbit` устанавливается только после того, как произведена попытка операции (например, чтения) за пределами файла. Т.е. надо писать так

    while(true) //метод eof() возвращает 1 если дошли до конца файла
    {
      in>>a;//читаем из потока(файла input.txt) одно значение
      if (in.eof()) break;
      s+=a;
    }

Comment: #include<cstdio>

int main()
{
    //freopen("y.in", "r", stdin);
    //freopen("y.out", "w", stdout);

    int a, s = 0;

    while(scanf("%d", &a) == 1)
    {
                      s += a;
    }

    printf("%d\n", s);

    return 0;
}

Вполне спокойно работает с консолью

Comment: Благодарю, сейчас исправлю.

Comment: Еще хорошая манера: всегда эксплицитно закрывать файловые потоки

     in.close();

Comment: А еще после ввода числа надо сначала проверять in.good(), а уже потом (если не гуд) на eof.

    while (1) {
      in >> a; 
      if (!in.good())
        break;  // и по eof тоже
      ....
    }
    if (i.eof()) 
      OK;
    else
      ERR;

Comment: @avp, совершенно верно. Только лучше проверять через метод `is_open()`

Answer (score 0):

```
while(true)
{
  in>>a;//читаем из потока(файла input.txt) одно значение
  if (in.eof()) break;
  s+=a;
}
```

лучше цикл с постусловием использовать (не нужно делать лишних проверок)

```
do {
    in >> a;
    s += a;
} while( !in.eof() );
```

Comment: @vitali0, попробуйте вместо цифры ввести буковку и посмотрите, что получится.

Comment: Смотрите, что получится. Положим, было считает n чисел из файла и достигнут его конец. При попытке считать новое число происходит ошибка и переменная а не изменяется, но так же содержит последнее считанные значение. Потом это значение опять прибавляется к общей сумме и цикл завершается. Видите ошибку? А общее число проверок в цикле не изменится.

Comment: Это ошибка с нормальными числами (ее еще осознать надо), а с буковкой просто зациклится. 

Не знаю, что лучше для обучения?

Comment: @mikillskegg, @avp по поводу проверок на корректность ввода Вы правы, я этого и не предусматривал